# what is value and what is position in for loop?

Tags: python

#code a

```
def skip_elements(elements):
    new_list = []
    i = 0
    for x in elements:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            new_list.append(x)
            i=i+1
    return new_list

print(skip_elements(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"])) # Should be ['a', 'c', 'e', 'g']
```

in code a
(for x in elements:) here x represent values in list(elements) a b c d e f g not its postion 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 and (if i % 2 == 0:) here i got stuck because "i" represent position how come i represent postion of value x

Comment: Try to run it by hand with pen and paper, and you will probably see...

Answer (score 1):

#### Fix

For now the problem is that `i` (position) is incremented only in the if, so it goes from 0 to 1, then you don't enter the `if` and the code only returns `['a']`, you need to increment at every round

```
def skip_elements(elements):
    new_list = []
    i = 0
    for x in elements:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            new_list.append(x)
        i = i + 1
    return new_list
```

---

#### Improve

Use `enumerate` that yields both the value, and a it's position

```
def skip_elements(elements):
    new_list = []
    for i, x in enumerate(elements):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            new_list.append(x)
    return new_list

# list-comprehension version
def skip_elements(elements):
    return [x for i, x in enumerate(elements) if i % 2 == 0]
```

Directly use a slice that takes one element over two

```
def skip_elements(elements):
    return elements[::2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def skip_elements(elements):
    new_list = []
    for i, x in enumerate(elements):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            new_list.append(x)
    return new_list


print(skip_elements(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]))
print(skip_elements(["Orange", "Pineapple", "Strawberry", "Kiwi", "Peach"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the index of the element by the *index()* method.

```
def skip_elements(elements):
    new_list = []
    for x in elements:
        if elements.index(x) % 2 == 0:
            new_list.append(x)
    return new_list
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple list slice as follows:

```
def skip_elements(elements):
  return elements[::2]
```